REDCap Survey title is not the same width as the survey on mobiles
I'm having an issue where I'm preparing a survey for a study that will mostly recruit older participants. The survey title is appearing as about half the width of the actual survey when I load the page on a mobile. This is an issue for us because the half the text of the survey is cut off from view as the page loads automatically to the width of the survey title. Our older participants may not know how to zoom out. Does anyone know why this is occurring and how I can fix it?
Thanks!
I have tried resizing any images or tables used but it hasn't resolved anything.
